# In SQL, I have a table of products and each product has a 2D table of details how can I link them?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am working on a project that compare the user measurements with clothes measurement and print the result and how much does it fit.

I have a `dresses` table which contain the `dress name` and its `ID` . But, each dress has its 2D table contains its different measurement (Shoulder, Bust, Length, etc...) in S,M,L,XL types. Something like this:

[image]

I tried linking using ID but it doesn't work.

How can I link each product with its table?

and How will the query look like in php?

Comment: please put code whatever you tried

Comment: The problem isn't with the code, the problem is with the tables' structure @rahul

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: I am using SQL!! @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the data structure to be more SQLish.  Having a separate table for each dress is not the way to go.

Instead, you need to combine all the "2D" tables into a single table.  One method would be to take the existing infrastructure and just add a dress id column:

```
DressId    S     M    L    XL
  1       74    78   80    84
. . .
```

I would recommend reformatting the data, into four columns:

```
DressId   Size   Measurement   Value
  1         S     shoulders      74
  1         M     shoulders      78
```

This process of restructuring the data is called normalization, and it is a big help when working with databases.

Comment: So each dress will have 16 row in the table?

Comment: @husseinmur . . . Based on the data you provided, yes.